# Hooking into Display Tag pagination events

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags, displaytag

Does the [Display tag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/) JSP tag provide a way to hook into pagination events, so that you can execute your own code when the user pages the data? I couldn't work out how to do it from the docs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at their [external pagination and sorting](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html)?

We use it and it works quite well.  Lets you implement your own paging and sorting.  Using this, if you have a large data set you can offload paging/sorting to your DB server to speed things up (a lot).

Comment: Thanks. I looked into that but couldn't see any callbacks that get invoked when a page link gets clicked.

Comment: If you just want to know when the user has clicked next/prev/page 1/etc, there will almost certainly be a HTTP parameter you can use..